Proving convergence and meromorphic continuation of Dirichlet Series Product F(s)=A(s)B(s)
I came across this question about the convergence and meromorphic continuation of a Dirichlet series product while investigating the properties of a particular integer sequence. I'd appreciate it if someone could confirm my reasoning. Please let me know if I've overlooked anything or if there's a more straightforward way to approach this.
I have a Dirichlet series:
$$F(s) = \sum_{n\geq1} \frac{f(n)}{n^{s}} = A(s)B(s)$$
where $A(s) = \sum_{n\geq1} \frac{a(n)}{n^{s}}$ and $B(s) = \sum_{n\geq1} \frac{b(n)}{n^{s}}$.  We have the following properties, where $0 < c_{0} < c$:

$f(n) = O(n^{\varepsilon})$  (for any $\varepsilon > 0$)
$a(n) = O(1)$
$b(n) = O(1)$
$b(n) \geq 0$
$\sum_{n\leq x} f(n) \ll x^{c}$
$\sum_{n\leq x} a(n) \ll x^{c_{0}}$
$\sum_{n\leq x} b_{n} \sim x^{c}$ (as $x \to \infty$)
$A(s)$ is analytic in the half-plane $Re(z) > c_{0}$

My Questions:

Convergence:  Does $F(s)$ converge in the half-plane $Re(z) > c$?  (I believe this follows from conditions 1 and 5, but I'm not sure because $f(n)$ is not necessarily positive).

Meromorphic Continuation: Does $F(s)$ have a meromorphic continuation to the half-plane $Re(z) \geq c$ with a simple pole at $s = c$ with residue $A(c)$? (I suspect this follows from $A(s)$ being analytic in this half-plane (8) and $B(s)$ having a pole at $s=c$ with residue $1$ from (7) and (3),(4)).


